# Multiple modules using the same jar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with several modules. Some modules depends on the same jar. Right now each of the modules have their own "libs" folder containing 2 jars of the same library. Updating a jar file can be problematic since I will now have to change all the jars from all of the modules. Also, I encounter a compilation problem saying that there are duplicate classes. One workaround is to remove the jar files from all of the modules except for one. Is this the only way to do it or is there a better way?

Comment: do not use a libs folder at all ... setup local maven repo(if library is not in jcenter/other online maven repo) ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been able to fix this issue. This [reading about Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Creating-a-Library-Project) helped me a lot. Here is what I have done:

Instead of putting the `JAR file` in `moduleA/libs folder`, I have imported the `JAR file` in `Android Studio` by clicking on the `project then right click -> new -> module`. I then clicked on `Import .JAR/.AAR package`. This created a `module containing the JAR file + a gradle script`.

Then, in `moduleA’s gradle script`, I have added this in the `dependencies`: `compile project(path: ':name_of_the_jar_file')`

I rebuilt all and it works. The `JAR file` is now present in the `APK` and there is no more crash at runtime.

Comment: When I try to Import the JAR file it will only let me select a folder that contains a Gradle or Android Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest android versions, the compile project is deprecated in build.gradle.
Then the below line can be added to include the build lib module.

```
dependencies {
     implementation project(path: ':name_of_the_module') 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new module just to have the common jar file in libs. And add this new module as dependency to the other modules that requires the jar file.

1. First create a new module, say, "commonJar". File -> New -> New Module -> Choose Android Library
2. Now, add the jar library to this module's libs folder.
3. Then, add this module as dependency in build.gradle of other modules. 
   compile project(':commonJar')

Comment: This doesn't give me access to the namespace/classes in the .jar file of the referenced module.