# Can't use Java library from module in app module

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the structure of my project:

```
MainApp
-- Module 1
-- Module 2
-- Module 3
----Java library
```

After upgrading gradle and Android Studio to `3.4.1`, the compilation fails because `MainApp` can't resolve dependencies from the java library imported into `Module 3`. 
If I move the library up to the `MainApp` module, this works fine, but I can't because the library is required by every module in the app.

Anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: Is the library a jar file?

Comment: yes, it's a working jar used across other java projects (and it used to work in Android before this major update)

Comment: You can add it into libs folder next to main folder. Then Resync.

Comment: If I add the jar to the app module, the other modules don't see it (a module has an independent scope), if I add the jar multiple times, I will get the duplicate symbols error

Comment: found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46709542/293918